# `if constexpr (false)` always evaluates to true

Tags: c++

From the [description on cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/if) I assumed that `if constexpr` would behave like a normal `if` but works at compile time.

The description says:

> In a constexpr if statement, the value of condition must be a contextually converted constant expression of type bool. If the value is true, then statement-false is discarded (if present), otherwise, statement-true is discarded.

`constexpr (false)` is obviously false, so the static_assert should be discarded, right? However, with the following code I always get a compilation error for the assertion:

```
if constexpr (false) {
  static_assert(false, "empty");
}
```

while I expected no compile error. This is XCode 10 with clang and C++17 enabled. Is that a problem of the compiler or is it me misunderstanding this concept?

By request (even though I think it's not relevant here): the compiler error I get is:

> Static_assert failed "empty"

Comment: The static_assert is not ill-formed.

Comment: "I always get a compilation error" - *What* error? Please, always include the text of any error messages in the question (verbatim).

Comment: When reading the reference did you happen to read "*Outside a template, a discarded statement is fully checked. if constexpr is not a substitute for the #if preprocessing directive"*

Comment: @MikeLischke `static_assert(false, ...);` is considered ill-formed: *"If the value of the expression when so converted is true, the declaration has no effect.
Otherwise, the program is ill-formed"* http://www.eel.is/c++draft/dcl.dcl#6

Comment: consider the example from cppref that starts with "Outside a template, a dscarded statement is fully checked."

Comment: In addition to the dupe, `static_assert(false, "")` is always ill-formed, no matter if it's in a template or not.

Comment: @JesperJuhl The error is what I wrote: the compiler error for the assertion, as if there was no `if constexpr (false)` part.

Comment: @MikeLischke That's not the error message. That is you paraphrasing the error message. What I was trying to say was: please always include *the exact, unmodified, text* of any error messages in the question. Just the way the compiler spits it out. I *get* what the error is in this case. I was just trying to provide some general advice.

Comment: I added another duplicate that explains how `static_assert(false, "")` won't compile even if not instantiated.

Answer (score 4):

Short answer: `static_assert(false)` should never appear in a *constexpr if* expression, regardless of whether it's in a template function or whether it's in the discarded branch.

---

From the same page you linked:

> Note: the discarded statement can't be ill-formed for every possible specialization:
>
> ```
> template <typename T>
> void f() {
>      if constexpr (std::is_arithmetic_v<T>)
>          // ...
>      else
>        static_assert(false, "Must be arithmetic"); // ill-formed: invalid for every T
> }
> ```

And that `static_assert(false, ...)` is a compilation failure *for every possible specialization*, so that `static_assert` always fires, even if the branch would be discarded.

Comment: From the description it is not clear that `if constexpr` only works in templates. There's even another non-templated example (with that not-defined variable x).

Comment: @MikeLischke This answer doesn’t claim that `if constexpr` only works in templates. It just says that the discarded branch mustn’t be unconditionally ill-formed (and `static_assert(false)` is by definition ill-formed).

Comment: Well, the answer only speaks about templates and ill-formedness for every possible specialization, which leads to the conclusion this only can work with templates. Could you please add a valid use of `if constexpr`, which does not appear in a template? That would help me to understand this better and I'd accept your answer.

Comment: @MikeLischke As said by others - whether it's in a template doesn't matter. What matters is that the "false branch" can't be unconditionally ill-formed.

Comment: @MikeLischke Or more precisely, `static_assert(false)` cannot appear in a *constexpr if* statement.